# How to run blocking operation in Corona SDK Lua?

Tags: sockets, asynchronous, tcp, lua, coroutine

I'm new to LUA and I'm writing a tcp messaging library in LUA using Corona SDK. I stuck with a problem that socket reading operation hangs application UI even if it is run in coroutine.

How I start coroutine:

```
function Messaging:readLoop()
   self.readCoroutine = coroutine.create(function() self:blockingLoop() end)
   coroutine.resume(self.readCoroutine)
end
```

Blocking loop:

```
function Messaging:blockingLoop()
   line,err,rest = self.sock:receive(BUFSIZE) -- <= Hangs UI if there is no incoming data 
end
```

Of course I know that coroutines are not equal to threads, but I expected that LUA interpreter switched to another coroutine on blocking operation (like Python threads with GIL).
Is there any possibility to read from socket without blocking UI? For example with real threading or async approach? Thanks.

P.S. Eliminating BUFSIZ is not the option since I don't want to have UI blocked at all, even for 0.2..0.4 seconds (slow mobile network delay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Corona contains LuaSockets](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/socket/index.html) which will let you do asynchronous socket communication, as seen [here](http://web-c2.anscamobile.com/forum/2011/06/06/code-snippet-how-do-non-blocking-multiplexed-raw-socket-transmission).

Answer (score 1):

Corona has a [network.request](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/request.html) API for Asynchronous calls..

If you do not want to use that, take a look at [this asynchronous http library](http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/cross-platform-asynchronous-http-request).

Comment: Unfortunately, it does HTTP request, but I need to work with sockets directly.

Comment: what about the second link?  I didn't go through it thoroughly, but it seemed like it was using socket connections..

Comment: The source of the second one really contains an async workaround, thanks. I'll try to compile something more o less working using that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on links posted by **Mud** and **SatheeshJM**, I finally made a messaging class which might be helpful for somebody

```
-- Messaging prototype
Messaging = {sock = nil, sockTimer = nil}

-- Messaging constructor
function Messaging:new (o)
   o = o or {}
   setmetatable(o, self)
   self.__index = self
   return o
end

function Messaging:connect()
   self.sock = socket.tcp()
   print( self.sock:connect(HOST, PORT) )
   self.sock:settimeout(0)
   self.sockTimer = timer.performWithDelay(50, function() self:checkData() end, 0)
end

function Messaging:close()
   timer.cancel(self.sockTimer)
   self.sock:close()
end

function Messaging:checkData()
   local data, status, rest = self.sock:receive()
   local s
   if data then
      s = data
   else
      s = rest
   end
   if s:len() ~= 0 then
      print ('received', s)
   end
end
```

Important notes:

1. **self.sock:settimeout(0)** required to make socket non-blocking
2. **local data, status, rest = self.sock:receive()** <- In most cased data will be in "rest" variable when "timeout" error appeared, that is why we need a check below to learn how exactly the data transfered